# How to use a variable over again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to Jquery and Javascript. I tried searching for an answer to my question on the site, but I am not sure if I am even using the correct terms to find my answer. If there is an answer already I would appreciate the link so I can look at it.

My question:
I am building a mobile app using HTML, CSS, Jquery and Javascript. It's an interactive CYOA type game/app. I used the following function to have the player enter their name:

```
<script> //to get player's name and use through out the game
function playerName ()
{
    var x;
    var player=prompt("Please enter your name");
if (player!=null)
    {
    x= " " + player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
    document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want to do is to be able to place the user's name through out the game. But I am not sure how I do that once the player initially enters their name in the prompt box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: just a note: when you already use jquery write `$("#logon").text(x);` instead of `document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;` this this will escape special chars, e.g. if the user name contains  `<` or `>`.

Comment: Thank you I will make the change.

Answer (score 5):

Create a single global namespace for your entire application, and put any relevant values there.

```
var MyApp = {};

MyApp.playerName = function () {
    var x;
    MyApp.player=prompt("Please enter your name");
    if (MyApp.player!=null) {
        x= " " + MyApp.player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
        document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
    }
}
```

You'll need to change your invocation of `playerName()` to `MyApp.playerName()`.

Comment: This is the right way to take care of this. Unfortunately, I have no more votes left for today :(

Comment: Okay, this is where I am confused. The player has entered their name, they continue onto the next "page" and I want to reuse their name:    <div class="friend" style="display:none;color:green;"><p>Hey [name], are you okay? You've been off grid for almost 20 minutes. What happened?</div>                How do I place the player name into this section (where I have it marked [name])?   Thank you for the quick reply I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @myeire: When you load a new page, you're loading an entirely new JavaScript environment. You'd either need to make it a single page application *(by updating the existing page with changes)*, or use some way to communicate the name to the next page, like cookies, localStorage, or embedding it in the page URL.

Comment: Oh! Local storage! I forgot about that. I think that's what I need. I better go google how to use local storage now! Thank you! But I still need to make the player name a global variable so I can use it with local storage correct?

Comment: @myeire: No, you'll store it directly in local storage, and retrieve it on the next page. On that next page you'll need to decide if it should be available globally, or not

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest something as simple as the following, so long as the `player` variable is defined outside of any functions (and here it is, since the value is returned from the function) it'll have global scope (you could also achieve this by omitting the `var` keyword, which makes the variable global scope *regardless* of where it's defined):

```
function playerName(){
    var name = prompt('What is your name?'),
        x;
    if (player) {
        x = " " + name + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
        document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
    }
    return name;
}
var player = playerName;
```

Answer (score 2):

I shutter to suggest this, but you can make the `player` variable global.

```
var player;

function playerName () {
    var x;
    player=prompt("Please enter your name");
    if (player!=null) {
        x= " " + player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
        document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the easiest way.. +1

Comment: @tymeJV Easiest is usually not the best. Especially in this scenario

Comment: This is where I'm confused. On the next "page" (and various pages as needed) I have this: <div class="friend" style="display:none;color:green;"><p>Hey [name], are you okay? You've been off grid for almost 20 minutes. What happened?</div> But how do I get the player name to show up where I have it marked [name]? Thank you for the quick reply I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You could add the player name to the URL of the following pages. But honestly, you're better off creating a session to preserve the state of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid making it global by scoping it like this:

```
(function() {
    var player;
    function playerName ()
    {
        var x;
        player=prompt("Please enter your name");
        if (player!=null)
        {
            x = " " + player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
            document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
        }
    }   
})();
```

The player variable is now accessible to any code that you write inside of the outermost function declaration (but not globally).

Comment: Yeah but you can never call `playerName` and get `player` outside of this closure...

Comment: I would add any code that needed to use player inside of the function. Generally I try to avoid making anything global.

Comment: I agree with that, but I doubt that OP would understand that from just the code

Comment: This is where I'm confused. On the next "page" (and various pages as needed) I have this:    <div class="friend" style="display:none;color:green;"><p>Hey [name], are you okay? You've been off grid for almost 20 minutes. What happened?</div>       But how do I get the player name to show up where I have it marked [name]? Thank you for the quick reply I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When you load a new page all of your javascript state will be reset. In other words you can't set a value in a javascript variable and then expect to use it after the page is reloaded. You need to either save this state on the client with cookies or localStorage, or save it on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had forgotten about local storage, so now I'm off to learn about that! But I would use the "var player" in local storage to be able to use the player's name over and over correct?

Comment: You'll want to use localStoarge.setItem and localStorage.getItem: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a gloval variable, outside the function:

```
var player='';
```

then You can set it from a function:

```
function myFunction(){ player='new name'; }
```

or read it:

```
function myOtherFunction(){ console.log(player) }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're facing is [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope). A variable is only visible from the block (think braces `{}`) it's declared in.

However, you can also access other variables that are already in an outer scope, such as `window`. to give an illustrated example:

```
alert(foo); // undeclared
alert(window.bar); // undeclared--so far...

function foo(){
  var foo = "foo";
  window.bar = "bar";

  alert(foo); // works -- "foo";
  alert(window.bar); works -- "bar";
}

alert(foo); // undeclared
alert(window.bar); // undeclared (still, haven't called foo() yet)

foo();
alert(window.bar); // "bar" (now it works)
```

this also applies to the name of functions and any other kinds of references you may have, However, in a case like this you can return a value from the function and avoid using a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

defining a global variable at the window level is typically the way to do this in jQuery - "window.player" in this case.  While you technically can make this global by simply omitting "var", it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would suffice to make a `player` object, like this:

```
var player = {};
```

Put that in your application, outside of any other functions.  Then, when you need to set a value on the player, for example, his/her name, put this in the function:

```
player.name = prompt("Please enter your name");
```

This way, you have that data accessible to you, but you don't have to use globals, which are variables created without the `var` keyword and widely considered pretty bad form.

Comment: I would normally suggest building a `new Player()` constructor, but that might be a bit beyond the questioner's need/ability at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the variable x through-out other functions and your script you can make it global, to make a variable global inside a function you can try this:

```
<script>
function foo() {
    window.newGlobalVariable = 'moo';
}
</script>
```

for example in your code:

```
<script> //to get player's name and use through out the game
function playerName (){

    widnow.x;
    widnow.player=prompt("Please enter your name");
   if (player!=null){
       x= " " + player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
       document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution (admittedly not the best) is to make `playerName` a property of the function. This exposes it without polluting global scope. Just demonstrating the capabilities of functions as objects in JS.

```
function playerName ()
{
    var x;
    var player=prompt("Please enter your name");
    if (player!=null)
    {
        x= " " + player + ", Please wait while the system updates your work orders";
        document.getElementById("logon").innerHTML=x;
    }
    playerName.player = player;
}
```

Comment: Does this not answer the question? It's actually the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178840/1022333 without introducing another object.